# Initial SVN Commit of VS ASP.NET project failed mid session due to power failure, best approach to restart?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 MVC3, C#, VS2012, MS SQL2008

I am using SVN with AnkhSVN in VS. I am also new to SVN and Source Control. So finally putting it all in place.

I tried an initial commit, and due to a power failure it stopped halfway through.

What should I now do? Delete the repo and restart or what?

Thanks.

EDIT/CONCLUSION

1. I deleted the files in the repo using the repo browser.
2. I removed versioning from VS, by deleting the .svn folder.
3. I then readded the solution to subversion, which imported all the folders.
4. This is now working well, and I have made about 20 commits over the last week and one tag.

Thanks to all, for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Subversion repo either passes or doesn't pass. If it is killed half way between, normally the commit will not have been in effect.

Since this is the initial commit, you might as well play it safe and redo the repository. However, it's very likely that the repo was not affected, and that the revision has not been committed.

Have you looked at the repository yet? There maybe a stuck transaction in the repo, but that will usually clear itself out unless you're using the Berkeley Database in your repository (the default is not to and on Windows, BDB is rarely used).

Comment: Thanks for this. If I am redoing the repository, I need to undo the Project Source control ie get rid of the AnkhSVN ticks. How can I rebase the VS Solution as far as SC is concerned ie to a point where no SC has happened.

Comment: You have the original sources? Just go to a clean directory and try everything again. Otherwise, take a look at the repo, and if everything is okay, then don't worry about it. Normally, you can't get the Subversion repo into a bad state because either a commit goes through or doesn't go through. The server will unwind incomplete transactions. AnkhSVN doesn't mess too much with the solution or project files. The main advantage is that AnkhSVN doesn't commit changes that aren't suppose to be checked in.

Comment: See Edit above for my final outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are safe alternatives to deleting your repository and starting over. It's very hard to assess the damage caused py a power failure. Stay on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for this. So are you suggesting that I should delete the repo and repeat? I notice also that my project in VS now has SVN/ANkhSVN ticks on quite a few files, so I guess I need to remove VC from the project. What would be the best approach to restarting the SVN process for a VS solution?